# Request permission infinite loop

Tags: android, google-maps

I downloaded sample source code from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap.

It crashed at the first time run caused by infinite loop between two functions:

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }
```

And run it on Emulator: api lvl25, Androd 7.1.1

Log:

```
03-22 23:34:18.249 24660-24660/com.example.mypc.mapdemo W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
03-22 23:34:19.759 24660-24660/com.example.mypc.mapdemo W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
03-22 23:34:20.501 24660-24660/com.example.mypc.mapdemo W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
03-22 23:34:20.894 24660-24660/com.example.mypc.mapdemo W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
```

Crash Log:

````
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.updateLocationUI(MainActivity.java:330)
                                                       at com.example.mypc.mapdemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4116)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:37
```2)
````

**Question: How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                updateLocationUI();
            }else{
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mLastKnownLocation = null;
           }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any descriptions for your answer?

Comment: just replace code of `requestpermission` `override` method

Comment: It fix the crash but my code doesn't work as my expectation. After I allowed permission the map doesn't move to my current location when I press `MyLocationButton`.

Comment: you need to enable location of your device

Comment: Add this permission also in your manifest,
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: test your app in real device

Comment: OK I will try it on real device. But your code resolved my problem so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                updateLocationUI();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after rewrite several times the way that onRequestPermissionsResult was coded I found that the issue got fixed adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

besides of:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

at AndroidManifest.xml

Good luck!